# not able to create campaign record even I have crud PERMISSION

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, error, permission-sets, sfdcmobilesdk-android

I want to create campaign record via script as new button was not there.But when i insert record it says

```
Line: 1, Column: 20
Field is not writeable: Campaign.Name
```

Even i am system admin .I have full CRUD access

```
Campaign newCamp = new Campaign(Name='EMEA Dist-Multi Channel Product/Marketing Info',isActive = true);
insert newcamp;
system.debug('campaign inserted successfully');
```

Comment: Name and few other fields are not writeable because those are managed by system directly, like createdDate, lastModifiedDate, CreatedBy etc. So remove `Name` field.

Comment: Refer to this [thread](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000094FXIAY) for more help on the same.

Comment: if i remove name field then how would i add campaign where name field is required

Comment: Have you ensured the Marketing user checkbox is checked on the admin profile?

Comment: no...please tell me how can i verify it...I means where can i find marketing user checkbox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have done a quick repro of the code snippet you provided in my org with the "Marketing user" checkbox enabled and it gives output as

> campaign inserted successfully

When disabled, it gives an error

> Field is not writeable: Campaign.Name

Click path to enable the Marketing user checkbox: Navigate to setup>Mange Users> Users> select the user and search for "Marketing User " checkbox. Make sure it is checked.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, it is a User field that is causing the problem. The User executing the piece of code must have Marketing User enabled in order to perform any database operation other than Read on Campaign records.

> When enabled and the user has Read permission on contacts or the Import permission on Leads, and Edit permission on campaigns, the user can create, edit, and delete campaigns, configure advanced campaign setup, and add campaign members and update their statuses with the Data Import Wizard. Available in Professional, Enterprise, Unlimited, and Performance Editions.
>
> If this option isn’t selected, or the user doesn’t have the necessary permissions, the user can only view campaigns and advanced campaign setup, edit the Campaign History for a single lead or contact, and run campaign reports.

As per [User Fields](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.user_fields.htm&type=5).